# Grafana API - How to switch current organization

Tags: api, grafana, grafana-api

The docs about organizations (http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/org/) use the words `current` and `actual` organization which shows that there is a kind of "active" organization which you deal with. To get "current" organization, I use:

```
GET /api/org
```

and get back:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Main Org.",
    "address": {
        "address1": "",
        "address2": "",
        "city": "",
        "zipCode": "",
        "state": "",
        "country": ""
    }
}
```

I have created some other test organizations, but **how do I switch current organization by using the Grafana API?**

---

Tests are being done with basic auth and the default administrator user (`admin:admin`). I notice that if I use the UI, the current organization is changing.

[image]

```
GET /api/org
```

now returns:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "organization_test_2",
    "address": {
        "address1": "",
        "address2": "",
        "city": "",
        "zipCode": "",
        "state": "",
        "country": ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With basic auth and username `admin` and password `admin`:

`curl -X POST http://admin:admin@localhost:3000/api/user/using/<id of new org>`

Docs for switching org: http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/user/#switch-user-context